# In Foundry Workshop, is it possible to change the theme to be dark mode?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

Is there a dark-mode available for Foundry Workshop? If so, how would one enable it?

Answer (score 4):

You can enable Dark Mode in Workshop by following these steps:

1. Click the Settings gear on the top left of your Workshop module
2. In the Settings panel, click to toggle the Theme of your Module between `Light` and `Dark` themes.

[image: Module settings gear]

[image: Workshop theme selector]